# seding data using socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to send data to server using socket.io-client but it is not working.

socket code :

```
var noble = require('noble');
var beacon_descover = require('./beacon_descover.js');
var io = require('socket.io-client')
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {reconnect: true});
var addressToTrack = 'x.x.x.x ';

socket.on('connect', function(){
console.log('connected to server');
});

noble.on('discover', function(peripheral){
if(peripheral.uuid == addressToTrack){
socket.emit('deviceData', {mac: peripheral.uuid, rssi:peripheral.rssi});
}
});

noble.startScanning([], true)
```

I get this Eroor

```
 Error: Could not start scanning, state is unknown (not poweredOn)
```

at Noble.scan 
at Noble.startScanning ...
Do anyone know how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not a SocketIO problem, this is a problem with Noble. 
And for future, use === comparison instead of == it saves you from strange problems on condition check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,It was noble problem. I solved it :

```
if(noble.state === 'poweredOn'){
    scanStart()
}else{

    noble.on('stateChange', scanStart)
}
```

Thank you for the advice.